# Prove the variance of the stochastic gradient

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent

Prove that the variance of the stochastic gradient with a mini-batch size of $S^{(i)}$ is equal to the variance with a mini-batch size of 1 divided by $S^{(i)}$, i.e., $v^{(i)}=$ $\frac{1}{S^{(i)}}$ $v_{s^{(i)=1}}^{(i)}$.

$v$ and $S$ denotes the variance for a mini-batch of size S

Comment: what is $v$ what is $S$ ?

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch It denotes the variance for a mini-batch of size S